# Notation: Relabelling elements of a (finite) set

Tags: combinatorics, notation

Often we construct sets to contain specific elements. For example,

1. Let $C$ be the set of cards in a standard deck,
2. Let $\mathcal G_n$ be the set of graphs on $n$ vertices,
3. Let $B_{n,k}$ be the set of all binary numbers of length $n$ containing precisely $k$ ones.

But sometimes we are not interested in the specific properties of the elements of such a set, but more in the set itself. So for simplicity, we relabel the cards in the set $C$, and deal with the set $\{1, 2, \dots, 52\}$, or the set $\{1, 2, \dots, {n\choose 2}\}$ in the case of $\mathcal G_n$, or the set $\{1, 2, \dots, {n\choose k}\}$ in the case of $B_{n,k}$.

My question is:

> Is there a notation which encapsulates that two sets are *equivalent up to relabeling*?

Seeing that sets are so often relabeled in mathematics, e.g. sets of vertices of a graph, events in a probability space, etc., I'd have thought there would be such a notation.

Comment: A set does not have much structure, as noted in the answer by @EikeSchulte.  You might also want to look at the notion of isomorphism in the general category theoretic sense and also for some specific types of objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is called *cardinality*. A relabeling is simply a bijective map $f:A\to B$ and two sets have the same cardinality whenever there is a bijection between them.

Comment: So the relation is simply $A \sim B \iff |A| = |B|$? (at least, for finite sets)

Comment: Yes, and even for infinite sets. As @Qudit commented above, it is this simple because sets don’t carry more information.