# Mathematical term describing two (redundancy allowed) sets are divided into same subsets

Tags: geometry, set-theory

It derived from another Stackexchange question in StackOverflow.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70106631/check-if-two-categorical-variables-are-virtually-same

I wonder if there is a mathematical term describing {A,B,B,A,C} (redundancy is allowed and the order of elements matters.) and {1,2,2,1,3} are the same thing.

More examples:

- {A,B,B,A,C} is different from {1,2,2,3,1} because of the order of elements
- {A,B,C} is different from {1,2,2,1,3}
- {A,B,B,B,B} is same as {85,43,43,43,43}

Comment: If order matters, these are sequences, not sets.  With sequences, repetition is allowed for free.  Then you are asking about sequences equivalent under relabelling.  (For a little more on relabelling, see the answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2517205/notation-relabelling-elements-of-a-finite-set/2517912 )

Comment: A specific one of these is a permutation of a multiset. I don't know if there is a name for two of these which are related by a bijection of the symbols used in one to those used in another.

Comment: Would $(1,2,2,1,3)$ count as same as $(3,1,1,3,2)$?

Comment: @Berci Yes. They are considered as same.

Comment: You could say they are isomorphic, with an isomorphism given by $i(A) =1$, $i(B) = 2$, $i(C) = 3$ .